# A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in p.exe

Tags: c++, oop, dma, jagged-arrays

## Main issue

- When i used void function instead of jagged it did'nt threw an exception.
- how should i release memory in destructor?
- **Thanks!**

## Explaination

It seems that my program is encountering a breakpoint instruction or a similar call exception, leading to program interruption during execution. Despite removing breakpoints and ensuring correct code logic, the issue persists. This interruption hampers the proper execution of the program and prevents further debugging. I seek advice on potential solutions to resolve this issue and ensure smooth program execution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

## Code

**Class of Jagged array**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Jagged {
private:
    int row;
    int* column;
    int** members;

public:
    // Default Constructor
    Jagged() : row(0), column(nullptr), members(nullptr) {}

    // Destructor
    ~Jagged() {
        if (column != nullptr) {
            delete[] column;
            column = nullptr;
        }

        if (members != nullptr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
                if (members[i] != nullptr) {
                    delete[] members[i];
                    members[i] = nullptr;
                }
            }
            delete[] members;
            members = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Input function
    Jagged Input();
    // Display function
    void Display();
};
```

**Input and output functions**

```cpp
Jagged Jagged::Input() {
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> row;

    column = new int[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        cout << "Enter the number of columns for row " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> column[i];
    }

    members = new int* [row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        members[i] = new int[column[i]];
        for (int j = 0; j < column[i]; j++) {
            cout << "Enter value for row " << i + 1 << " and column " << j + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> members[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

void Jagged::Display() {
    cout << "\nJagged Array:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        cout << "Row " << i + 1 << ": ";
        for (int j = 0; j < column[i]; j++) {
            cout << members[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

**Main function**

```cpp
int main() {
    Jagged J1;
    J1.Input();
    J1.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this C++? If it is, can you add the appropriate tag?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)